# Command Line or Powershell option to change desktop background folder

Tags: windows-10, command-line, desktop-customization

I am looking for a way with script to change the folder that is used for desktop background slideshows (see image below):

[image]

There have been multiple questions on SuperUser about changing the [background color](https://superuser.com/questions/850989/change-windows-desktop-background-command-line), [accent color](https://superuser.com/questions/1780782/how-to-change-theme-background-settings-in-windows-10-automatically-or-with-one), or how to [advance the slideshow to the next picture](https://superuser.com/questions/1780841/next-desktop-background-by-cmd-powershell-or-batch) via command line, but I haven't found anything that asks (or answers), how to set the directory for the slideshow via command line or script.

I've tried

`reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d E:\pics\X\bee old\pics \f`

then following up with:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Also tried :

```
reg add "HKCU\control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "E:\pics\X\bee old\pics\" /f
```

then following up with:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

but this does neither of these change anything.

There are some good techniques shown in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1244726/598567), however I do not want to have to kill explorer to make any changes. I'd like to explore the idea of swapping out the `slideshow.ini` file stored in  `~\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\` but this requires a restart of explorer (how does the Windows desktop manager change this without restarting explorer? HMMM).

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=wallpaper+powershell

Comment: Why do you not want to kill explorer.exe? You can just restart it.

Comment: @Gantendo because I use an Explorer shell called [QTTabBar](http://http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/) that remembers all my open tabs. Killing Explorer via CMD prevents QTTabBar from saving the tabs so all my tabs are lost when Explorer is restarted.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1814025/17025 for an automation-based approach. (Should this be a duplicate of that question?)